# Unpack variable length list of dictionaries using Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a payload that is a list that will contain a variable number of dictionaries and I was hoping to be able to unpack that via a single call to a pydantic model.

Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish, with two dictionaries:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9

from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Dict

class RequestPayload(BaseModel):
    site: str

class RequestPayload_unpack(BaseModel):
    endpoints: List[Dict, RequestPayload]

payload = [
    {
        'site': 'nyc01',
    },
    {
        'site': 'lax02',
    },
]

request = RequestPayload_unpack(*payload)
print(request)
```

Running that I get the following error:

```
    raise TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.List; actual 2, expected 1
```

The workflow that I have working now (not using pydantic) parses/validates each dict in the list and then passes it along to the next step, which will perform additional lookups and then eventually do the work. So right now the model is that the entire `RequestPayload` is operated upon through the pipeline, versus each dict being treated as a distinct request.

Comment: `endpoints: List[Dict, RequestPayload]` should be `endpoints: List[RequestPayload]`

Comment: This has *nothing to do with argument unpacking*.

Comment: And just some suggestions, but `class RequestPayload` should probably be called `class Endpoint`, and `class RequestPayload_unpack` should be called `class RequestPayload`. "unpack" doesn't make any sense here. So then everthing under `class RequestPayload(BaseModel):` is just `endpoints: list[Endpoints]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the assistance. thinking about it further, my approach is wrong for what I need to do.